# What after pull request merge?

Tags: git

Suppose I am working on a feature branch on my local computer. Now after certain commits, I make a pull request.

Now, assume my pull request has been accepted and the feature branch is merged into development branch in remote. Now, after that what happens to my local feature branch. Will it also gets merged automatically on my local system or I have to merge it into devel myself?

If I merge it myself, do I need to first do git pull to update my local development branch?

Comment: If it is merged on the dev branch remotely you can simply pull the dev branch locally to get updated dev branch.

Comment: Ok, but what to do with local feature branch ?

Comment: for the local feature branch if it is already merged into dev you can simply delete that as it is available in the dev branch and any time you can get that from dev branch.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase my question again. Once you accept the pull request, you will merge your origin/feature into origin/develop. Now, when I do this  I am generating a new commit which is definitely at remote only. Now, if I do git pull on my local devel, I will get this extra commit on my local devel also. But, my local feature is still hanging. Now, if do merge of feature to my devel on local, I am again generating an extra commit. So, now my local is ahaed of remote by one commit. Finally to align everything I can do git push. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You always make changes to your feature branch until your feature has been fully developed. Once feature is fully developed, you go through merge request and then if your changes look fine. They are merged into develop branch. While creating pull request, you can select "Delete source branch once pull request is accepted" in the UI, or else you have to delete branch manually.

Once branch is merged, develop branch is updated, but in your local system `develop` branch is not updated. So, you will have to run `git pull` to update your develop branch. It is not automatic.

Comment: Hi Piyush, thanks a lot for your prompt response. I understand your point that merging at remote after pull request will make changes to my remote. Now, after that I do git pull to update my local devel branch. But what about my local feature branch. Remote feature is merged to origin/develop but how to handle local feature branch?

Comment: You should keep it as it is in local. After few days if you think that feature is complete. Then you can delete that branch using `git branch -d <branch_name>`.

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain it using a small example. Consider an initial setup of some remote repository.

```sh
# Your initial remote repository setup
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- origin/develop , origin/HEAD


# You checked things into your local then git copies would be:
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- origin/develop , origin/HEAD

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop , HEAD


# You create separate brach 'feature' out of it and add two commits to it:
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- origin/develop , origin/HEAD

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- feature, HEAD


# You checked in remotely and raised pull-reqeust:
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- origin/develop, origin/HEAD
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- origin/feature 

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- feature, HEAD
```

You merged the `feature` branch into `develop` remotely, here things may go nasty. There are two possible outcomes:

1. Fast-forward merge <- easiest one.
2. 3-way merge <- tricky one, will not happen in your case. Therefore, skipping its explanation for a while.

If a Fast-forward merge happens. It happens when you don't get any merge conflicts. Like, in this case, you will never encounter since only one developer is active and only one branch in being checked-in.

```sh
# Fast-forward merge happens
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- origin/develop, origin/HEAD, origin/feature 

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- feature, HEAD
```

Now let us say, you kept on working on your local `feature` brach and added two more commits, then:

```sh
# Added two more commits on local branch:
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- origin/develop, origin/HEAD, origin/feature 

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop
                  \
                 hash4---hash5---hash6---hash7 <- feature, HEAD

# You checked local 'feature' branch's code in and raised a pull-request.
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 
                  \
                 hash4---hash5 <- origin/develop, origin/HEAD
                            \
                            hash6---hash7 <- origin/feature 

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop
                  \
                 hash4---hash5---hash6---hash7 <- feature, HEAD


# You merged local 'feature' branch's into develop branch.
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 
                  \
                 hash4---hash5
                            \
                            hash6---hash7 <- origin/develop, origin/HEAD, origin/feature

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 <- develop
                  \
                 hash4---hash5---hash6---hash7 <- feature, HEAD
```

Now, let us say you merged your remote `origin/develop` changes into local `develop` branch, then:

```sh
## Your remote repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 
                  \
                 hash4---hash5
                            \
                            hash6---hash7 <- origin/develop, origin/HEAD, origin/feature

## Your local repository's snapshot would look like:
hash1---hash2---hash3 
                  \
                 hash4---hash5---hash6---hash7 <- <- develop, feature, HEAD
```

If you look closely the above layout, then both are same. Although, there is small difference is their representation, but that is what I itentionally did to explain the merge concepts to you.

In conclusion, it totally depends on you wheather you still want to work on that branch or you can simply drop it becuase in the end branch is just a determined pointer to some fixed hash on your git graph.